# Not be able to retrieve entity types from FIWARE Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I want to retrieve all the entity types that has been defined in the Orion context broker. I searched the tutorials and find [this](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.15.0/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#browsing-all-types-and-detailed-information-on-a-type). But this API give an empty message: `[]`.

I have also tried to add other headers like `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicepath` but it made no difference.

P.S:

this is the API I used for getting all the entity types :

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/types -s -S -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

and this is another one with two aforementioned headers :

```
curl 178.252.170.26:1026/v2/types -s -S -H 'Accept: application/json'\
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause of getting `[]` as response to [`GET /v2/types`](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#list-entity-types-get-v2type) is that you don't have any entity in that service/subservice at all.

Do [`GET /v2/entities`](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#list-entities-get-v2entities) to check it. If the result is `[]` then my hypothesis gets confirmed. You can try to create some entity (using [`POST /v2/entities`](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#create-entity-post-v2entities)) and try again.

Comment: There exist multiple entities but no reponse for GET /v2/types !

Comment: Do you mean that `GET /v2/entities` shows several entities but `GET /v2/types` doesn't show any result (in both cases with the same `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicepath` headers)?